# What is this item?

Tags: electrical, hardware

I'm buying a house built in 1949. This item is located outside near the front door, door bell and mail slot. Anyone know what it is?[image]

Comment: take the cover off and look inside

Comment: The ugliest disconnect ever made? I wouldn't touch it. Don't inhale the dust from your siding either.

Comment: the metal handle indicates that the part in the middle probably unplugs ... maybe it is an electrical connection for reading some meter

Comment: Screw pattern looks like a switch.

Comment: Just speculation, but perhaps a switch cover to prevent people from turning the switch on or off?

Comment: Old-stye weatherproof switch, IMHO. Try moving the metal bail. Or just plan to update it, if it's still in service.

Comment: @Ecnerwal as fun as it is to "just try" things, at this age of the components I'd sure try to find out what it's wired to, if anything, before possibly powering up some circuit that's gone decrepit.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a standard toggle switch with a translucent weather-resistant cover.

As to what it might control... You'll have to figure that out by tracing wires, or by flipping it and seeing what happens. Could be anything from a patio light that no longer exists to a garage door opener to...

Answer (score -1):

A wild guess: some sort of recessed cord reel?

I think you are going to have to remove the cover and see what is behind...and post a picture...I cannot wait to see what is back there!